# Apply background color of specific cells in smartgwt ListGrid

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I started developing with smartgwt few weeks ago and I am having a problem I want to insert background color in specific cells of a ListGrid. The problem is that i have not access in ListGrid Elements with their indexes (for example grid(i,j)) 
Any idea?? 
Thank you

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283333/2208271. Its possible to use other CSS attributes to set background color, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways i can think of to achieve this:

1)Hilites.Good for coloring rows based on criterion. http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_hiliting_formula

2)Create custom cell canvases by overriding createRecordComponent() , updateRecordComponent() and showRecordComponent()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hilite which depend on a set of criteria which will allow you to apply a css rule on some record which satisfy the criteria. For the column you set a criteria which say field so&so equal xxx , for row number a quick solution(I don't know if you can set criteria on a row index)  will be to have a hidden field which you feed with an incrementing value and where you can set a criteria on this field value.