# SmartGWT: is it possible to color a a certain row in a list grid?

Tags: java, gwt, row, smartgwt, listgrid

all is it possible to color a certain Row in smartGWT listGrid ?
i want to color just 1 row , not all the listGrid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles. I guess the this link should help you

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja, that question is related to GWT & not to SmartGWT.

Answer (score 10):

In SmartGWT, methods that end with Style (e.g.- get*Style, getBaseStyle, getCellStyle, etc.) need to return a CSS class defined elsewhere (.css file, inline css in application load jsp, etc.).

Same applies for set*Style methods.

Unless lot of CSS customizations are done warranting the need for such, using [getCellCSSText](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_add) would probably be the best option.

getCellCSSText returns CSS text per cell, and will be called during every redraw.

```
final ListGrid resultsGrid = new ListGrid() {
    @Override
    protected String getCellCSSText(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
        String style = super.getCellCSSText(record, rowNum, colNum);

        // conditions can check values in record using rowNum, colNum as well as record attributes
        if (record.getAttribute("<grid-field-name>").equals(<value>)) {
            if (this.getFieldName(colNum).equals("<certain-grid-field-name>") && record.getAttribute("<grid-field-name>").equals(<specific-value>)) {
                style = "font-weight:bold"; // only that cell in that row becomes bold
            } else {
                style = "color:red"; // all other cells in that row become red
            }
        } else if (record.getAttribute("<other-grid-field-name>").equals(<value>)) {
            style = "color:green"; // entire row changed to green if one column in this row contain a specific value
        }

        return style;
    }
};
```

Its not required to extend ListGridRecord as indicated in showcase sample linked above, unless there are other reasons to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Never used SmartGWT, but looking at the JavaDoc, I'd say:

[`listGrid.getRecord(recordNum)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getRecord%28int%29)

- [`setCustomStyle(String customStyle)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridRecord.html#setCustomStyle%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`setAttribute(String property, BaseClass value)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/core/DataClass.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20com.smartgwt.client.core.BaseClass%29)

Also checkout this [sample](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_replace), that overrides the [`getBaseStyle()`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getBaseStyle%28%29) of the `ListGrid`.

Comment: The problem with `setCustomStyle()` is that you lose the original styling afterwards.

Comment: You can get back the original styling if you set setCustomStyle(null)